# Outlook addin activation on mobile

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

We have developed a javascript add-in for Outlook. When we install it using PowerShell command to O365, it is showing up in Outlook for Android and Outlook for iOS as expected. 
If we install it to a hosted Exchange (2013 and 2016), the add-in is not visible in Outlook 2013. 
In mobiles there is an another problem. If I go in Outlook for Android to the 'Settings/Add-ins', I can only select my O365 account, but can't select the hosted accounts, where I can activate my addin.

In the manifest xml file we have the following:

```
...
<Requirements>
    <Sets>
        <Set Name="MailBox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
</Requirements>
...
<VersionOverrides 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
<Description resid="appDescription" />
<Requirements>
  <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
    <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
  </bt:Sets>
</Requirements>
... 
<!-- Override for mobile apps -->
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
<Description resid="appDescription" />
    <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
           <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
        </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
...
```

Do you have any idea why is the add-in not showing up on hosted Exchange servers?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/outlook-mobile-addins):

> Outlook Mobile Add-ins are supported on all Office 365 Commercial accounts, Outlook.com accounts, and support is coming soon to Gmail accounts.

Comment: So does it mean that on onprem exchage 2013 and 2016 are not supported?

Comment: That is correct. Only mailboxes hosted by O365 and Outlook.com are supported (and Gmail soon). The only scenario I'm not 100% sure about is hybrid Exchange/Exchange Online. I suspect it wouldn't support them but I've never tested it to be sure.

Comment: Is there some documentation re: working with Gmail accounts for Outlook addins? How would one pull an email from Gmail server? Thanks